# How to generate "Faces" using the PCL Fast Organized Mesh method?

Tags: c++, intel, point-cloud-library, pcl

In order to generate a mesh with the intel RealSense D455, I used the PCL library and more precisely the Fast Organized Mesh method. I manage to generate a mesh in OBJ format but it only contains vertices and no faces.

Here is the code I used:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
cloud->resize(size);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cloud->at(i).x = Cloud[i].x;
    cloud->at(i).y = Cloud[i].y;
    cloud->at(i).z = Cloud[i].z;

}

std::cout << "Fast mesh started " << "\n";
pcl::OrganizedFastMesh<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr orgMesh(new pcl::OrganizedFastMesh<pcl::PointXYZ());
pcl::PolygonMesh triangles;
orgMesh->setTriangulationType(pcl::OrganizedFastMesh<pcl::PointXYZ>::TRIANGLE_RIGHT_CUT);
orgMesh->setInputCloud(cloud);
orgMesh->reconstruct(triangles);
std::cout << "start saving the fast mesh obj..." << "\n";
pcl::io::saveOBJFile("Mesh.obj", triangles);
```

Can someone explain how to make the method generate faces too?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe you have to set `triangles.cloud` before calling `reconstruct`. Something like `pcl::toPCLPointCloud2(*cloud, triangles.cloud)`. Can you try that?

Comment: Yes, I just added the line you suggested before calling reconstruct and still no face generated.

Comment: Can you print `triangles.polygons.size()`, `triangles.cloud.width`, `triangles.cloud.height`, and `triangles.cloud.data.size()`, just before calling `saveOBJFile`?

Comment: Yes sure, this are the results : Size of polygons :0
Height is :1
Width is :407040
data size is :6512640

Comment: What are `height` and `width` of `cloud` (the one you give to `orgMesh`)? Also height=1 and width=407040 I assume?

Comment: Yes exactly ! the Height is 1 and Width 407040

Comment: Ok, then that is the problem. Your point cloud is _unorganized_. `OrganizedFastMesh` can only work with _organized_  point clouds. The documentation also tells you that: https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_organized_fast_mesh.html#details . See here for more information about organized and unorganized point clouds: https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/master/basic_structures.html

Comment: And there is no way to convert an unorganized point cloud to an organized point cloud I guess ?

Comment: I would say if you point cloud is unorganized, your best bet is to use a method that can work with unorganized point clouds. Maybe `GreedyProjectionTriangulation` https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_greedy_projection_triangulation.html

Comment: I am using it too, but there is no texture in the OBJ. I didn't found a way to add the texture yet

Answer (score 1):

You are giving an unorganized point cloud as an input to an `OrganizedFastMesh` instance. But it is an API for an organized point cloud as the name implies. An organized point cloud means the points are already arranged as a mesh(like a matrix). See [the reference on PointCloud](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#details) and [an explanation on an organized point cloud](https://www.mathworks.com/help/lidar/ug/organized-and-unorganized-point-clouds.html)(on Mathworks) for details.

Use other APIs such as the `ConvexHull`.

Comment: I am not sure why triangles.cloud.height returns 1 (which would mean I have an unorganized point cloud). The original point cloud I have is organized (the height is 480, the width is 848). I haven't checked all the points of course but I have organized them by x, y (and the z that goes with each x,y pair). What is the expected structure for an organized point cloud ?

Comment: Just specify the width and height by using resize() or a constructor with the width and height parameters.